# Is there a one-liner to list a directory two levels deep where the second level is an only-child, but not known?

Tags: python

Suppose you have a directory structure like this:

```
A/
   B/
      a.1
      b.2
      c.3
```

I'm wondering if there's a way, knowing that B has no siblings AND NOT KNOWING B's NAME, to do an `os.listdir` operation in one swoop (that is, *without* calling os.listdir twice), instead of in three commands like so:

```
root = "A"
secondLevel = os.listdir(root)[0]
listing = os.listdir(os.path.join(root,secondLevel))
```

Comment: Are you worrying about the first listdir call being expensive? You need to get the name of that directory _somehow_...

Comment: `listing = os.listdir(os.path.join("A", os.listdir(root)[0]))` is one line.

Comment: @delnan I edited the question in response to your comment

Comment: @jakob yes, wondering if I could get around that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import glob
os.listdir(glob.glob('A/*')[0])
```

or maybe even

```
glob.glob('A/*/*')
```

Comment: Be aware though, that glob is almost certainly doing more work than the single listdir call in the original question. It needs to do at least the listdir, and then some pattern matching on top of that.

Comment: wont work if theres a file in the directory, i got index out of range

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: This is also a good solution, in general, but I find @ephemient's solution more to the point.